# How to group by a common value and get all the different values without an aggregation function

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this is a somewhat common question and I've looked through the ones I found but I rly don't understand how to do this.

If I have a table that stores the name of a customer and gives it a unique id like so:

Table customers:

```
CustomerId   CustomerName
1            Borislav
2            Jegveni
```

I have another tables that stores products names and an unique Id, same as the customers table, like so:

Products Table:

```
ProductId   ProductName

1           Artificial Grass
2           Light Bulb
3           Welding Mask
```

And finally I have a table that stores what products each user has bought, like so:

Customers Acquisitions:

```
UserWhoBoughtId    ProductBoughtId
1                  1
1                  2
1                  3
```

Now, I want to select every customer and what they have bought

```
. . .
SELECT * FROM customers
LEFT JOIN Acquisitions ON CustomerId  = UserWhoBoughtId
LEFT JOIN  Products ON ProductId  = ProductBoughtId
. . .
```

As I understand correctly `GROUP BY` works by grouping by the common values in this case we could group by customerId, but that would give multiple rows because the products are different, have different values, so in order to get only one row per user you would need to use and aggregation function to tell the group by what to do with the columns that have different values.

Not sure this is a very good example but basically my question is, is there a way I can group by the customerId and still get every value from Customers Acquisitions in one result ? So I can then show what each customer has bought ?

Comment: You can use `Group_Concat()` function on productid, to get all the product(s) purchased by the customer in a comma-separated string

Comment: you can use group_concat then you get a column customer and and one  all product bought separated by comma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) which will give you 1 row for each customer with all the products in a comma separated list:

```
SELECT c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName,
  group_concat(p.ProductName) Products
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Acquisitions a ON c.CustomerId = a.UserWhoBoughtId
LEFT JOIN Products p ON p.ProductId = a.ProductBoughtId 
GROUP BY c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName
```

If you don't want duplicate products use:

```
group_concat(distinct p.ProductName)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hsfokhbRiP9u7ox5VoHYdk/0).
Results:

```
| CustomerId | CustomerName | Products                                 |
| ---------- | ------------ | ---------------------------------------- |
| 1          | Borislav     | Artificial Grass,Light Bulb,Welding Mask |
| 2          | Jegveni      |                                          |
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you do this in your front end, often by making separate queries - one to get your users and one to get the product list (repeated for each one). What you describe could be done with GROUP_CONCAT in mysql.

```
SELECT customers.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Product.ProductName) AS products FROM customers 
LEFT JOIN Acquisitions ON CustomerId  = UserWhoBoughtId
LEFT JOIN  Products ON ProductId  = ProductBoughtId
GROUP BY customers.CustomerId
```

This will give you a string of the product names separated by a comma.